# How to run one task multiple times in Gulp

Tags: gulp

I want to run one task with different parameters multiple times. Something like:

```
gulp task --param value1 task --param value2
```

Is that possible? When I run the command above, the `task` is executed only once.

Comment: you can pass multiple params as comma separated and do multiple runs within the single task

Answer (score 0):

Run this in series and not parallel?

1. gulp task --param value1
2. gulp task --param value2